# Why is this variable not initialized when conditional statement is always entered?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Running this code results in the error "Variable 'message' used before being initialized" on the last line.

```
var message: String

if true {
    message = "Hello, world"
}

println(message)
```

Since the `if` statement is always `true`, why does the compiler think `message` is not initialized? Maybe this is a bug?

This example works:

```
var message: String

var n = 70
if n < 50 {
    message = "n is less than 50"
} else {
    message = "n is greater than or equal to 50"
}

println(message)
```

Removing the `else` statement results in the same error as above, but this time it's expected, since `n` may potentially be be greater than or equal to 50.

Comment: It is the else that allows it to compile. The else says no matter what it is going to get set, if no where else, here. It doesn't determine the validity of the if statement at compile time

Comment: Thanks @zgc7009. That makes sense. I wasn't sure if the compiler at least checked that the result would always be true, but thinking about it more, I suppose it really has no way to be sure.

Comment: Be thankful the compiler does 'flow analysis'...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a bug.

The compiler did not consider the current result of the expression inside the if statement.
What compiler understand is that this if statement can be false also.

So if it is false, then using message variable println(message) is a compilation error.

This can be ignore also depending on the warning level of your compiler, this kind of warning can be ignore or not.
Check your compiler settings.

Answer (score 0):

var message: String!    (adding ! will fix it.)

! = unwrapping the variable or what ever you put it after, just like ? means optional.